# Payment methods are not displaying in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using **[woocommerce_checkout]** to display checkout section on one page but, payment methods are not displaying in it.

But, when I go to Woocommerce's default checkout page then, payment methods are displaying there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-You forgot to change **Checkout Page** option.

-Please follow following steps.

1. Go to ***Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout -> Checkout Options***
2. Under *Checkout Pages* section you will see ***Checkout Page*** option. Select page in which you have posted  `[woocommerce_checkout]`.
3. Click on *Save Changes*.
4. Now go to the page which you have been selected in step 2.

-Hope you will see expected changes in the selected page.

Comment: you're welcome. Happy to help!